# Loop in R is ignored by program under certain circumstances

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a for loop that is for some reason ignored when I add an additional line of code. I've tested the line of code independently and the for loop independently, and both work as expected.

Here is the code:

```
onestar <- 0
twostar <- 0
threestar <- 0
fourstar <- 0
paste(ccdata[1,3],"*")
for (i in 1:ncol(ccdata))
{
    for (j in 1:nrow(ccdata)){#iterate down the list
        cat(ccdata[j,i])
        if (ccdata[j,i]<=0.05){
            onestar <- onestar+1
            x <- paste(ccdata[j,i],"*")
            ccdata[j,i]<-x
            cat(ccdata[j,i])
            ccdata[j,i]<-paste(ccdata[j,i],"*")
        }
    }
    cat("loopsruns")
}
onestar
```

I am having problems with the `ccdata[j,i]<-paste(ccdata[j,i],"*")` line -- when I remove it, the loop works fine. When it is included, the program just ignores the loop.

Alternately, if there's a package to label things according to statistical significance, that would be very helpful -- I googled it but wasn't able to find any.

Comment: Two points: 1. the line `paste(ccdata[1,3],"*")` is not saving the result anywhere; 2. the line `ccdata[j,i]<-paste(ccdata[j,i],"*")` converts matrix `ccdata` to `character`, causing the comparison `ccdata[j,i]<=0.05` to be done *lexically*, i.e., converting first `0.05` to the string `"0.05"`.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much, I hadn't realized that that was a lexical comparison, that also resolves some issues I was having later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `symnum` function to create labels according to statistical significance. For example, if `pvals` is a vector of p-values:

```
symnum(pvals, cutpoints = c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1), 
       symbols = c("***", "**", "*", ".", " "))
```